# Family portrait

Tags: riddle, knowledge

- I am new!
- I love my siblings.
- Get that onion off me! It smells!
- I am a saint.
- I burned and risen.
- I am an angel.

Where are we from and where are we to?

Comment: We are from and we are to Puevfg(Rot13).

Comment: That last bullet point: definitely just *one* angel rather than several?

Comment: Could you clarify the last bullet point please? My answer below makes an assumption about it and I'd like to know where it stands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you may be ...

> [From **sea** to **shining sea**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America_the_Beautiful#Idioms)

Because ...

```
I am new!
```

> New York City

```
I love my siblings.
```

> the city of Brotherly Love, Philadelphia

```
Get that onion off me! It smells!
```

> Chicago - the most accepted origin of which is a French translation of the word "shikaakwa" which in an Algonquin dialect means "stinky onion".

```
I am a saint.
```

> St. Louis, presumably, though other cities might probably also work.

```
I burned and risen.
```

> Phoenix, referencing the mythical bird.

```
I am an angel.
```

> Presumably Los Angeles, but Gareth's question in the comment is very relevant.

If you follow along with me you'll see

> that these are major US cities along a course from east coast to west, or as the American patriotic song "America the Beautiful" famously phrases it, "from sea to shining sea."

Comment: I did not know that about the onion. I had the sibling-loving and the burned-and-risen, which made it clear what sort of thing was going on. I have to admit I was hoping it would end up being something more specific...